# Universal in-app purchase on iOS and macOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, in-app-purchase

Has anyone successfully implemented universal in-app purchase for iOS and macOS?
I'm having trouble getting products in non-Catalyst macOS app with SKProductsRequest. They are returned as invalidProductIdentifiers.

What I have so far:

1. Single App Store connect record for both iOS and macOS
2. Same BundleID for both apps
3. Same in-app purchase product ID
4. Build with Xcode 11.4
5. Product fetch works on iOS

Apple announced that this will work for non-Catalyst apps as well and that it is enabled by default for Catalyst apps. Assuming this is not enabled by default in macOS apps how can I make this work?

Answer (score 7):

Now works after I did this:

1. Archive and upload a macOS build to App Store Connect and wait about 15 min
2. Restart computer

Hope this helps anyone who is looking for a solution for this.

Comment: My issue may be similar.  I've create a universal app from an existing iOS app, but when calling SKProductsRequest when running on my Mac, nothing happens.  No error, but the  func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) { is not called.  Is there different IAP code needed when running on a Mac vs iOS device?

Comment: @gbotha there is also `func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error)` function. Check if that one is called.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out my error.  I hadn't made a strong reference to the SKProductsRequest.  This didnt' cause an issue with all my iOS apps but failed with the macOS version.  I just put " var request: SKProductsRequest! " and now the macOS catalyst app finds the iap product details fine now.

Comment: You are a genius! I was going to waste a technical request on this because I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong. I just had to restart the computer!!! Another bug I found and like to mention is that after you archive the project for Mac, if you try to Validate it, you get an error. The solution is not to validate but just press the Distribute button and upload the build to the App Store.

Comment: @Alex that did it.

Comment: Restarting is all I had to do to fix the same issue.